# FHIR: Use of web categories

Tags: hl7-fhir

In DSTU1, web categories were used for tags and security tags and (in one of Ewout's connectathon presentations) for profiles.

However, in DSTU2 (May Ballot) I can only find a reference on one of the security tag pages.

Question is: are Web Categories still expected, or has their use be replaced by the meta element?

Answer (score 0):

According to Marten, $meta replaces categories.  http://thefhirplace.com/2015/03/17/metadata-in-fhir/

Comment: Here's the dangling reference:  http://hl7.org/fhir/2015May/security-labels.html#2.13.1.3

Comment: Task to fix this: http://gforge.hl7.org/gf/project/fhir/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=8178